# В чём заключается ошибка в коде? C++

Tags: c++, c, графы

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C2143   синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "константа"
Ошибка  C2065   сase: необъявленный идентификатор
Ошибка (активно)    E0020   идентификатор "сase" не определен

Моей задачей была реализация программы, которая сможет переводить из одного типа графа в другой (из матрицы инцидентности в матрицу смежности и т.д). Непонятно почему компилятор выдаёт ошибку, что не понимает что такое "case". Иногда и другие ошибки выводит. Просмотрите код, может найдёте в чем дело?( Для удобства также загрузил код на github: https://github.com/EverSo22/repos/blob/main/main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

//объявляем и определяем структуру для списка //смежности
typedef struct _node
{
        int  value;
        struct _node *next;
}
node;
//---------------------------------------------------
               //процедуры варианта выбора
void MIin();   //ввод матрицы инцидентности
void MSin();   //ввод матрицы смежности
void SSin();   //ввод списка смежности

         //процедуры ввода
void readArray(int *, int, int);    //матрицы
node *readList();           //списка смежности
    
         //процедуры вывода
void printArray(int *, int, int);   //матрицы
void printList(node *);        //списка смежности
         //процедуры преобразования
//м. инцидентности -> м. смежности
void MI_MS(int *, int *, int, int);               
//м. смежности -> список смежности
void MS_SS(int *, int, node **);          
//список смежности -> м. инцидентности
void SS_MI(int *, int , node **);         

          //дополнительные
//подсчёт элементов списка смежности
int countInList(node **, int);      
//освобождение памяти для строки из списка
void destroy(node *);               

int main()
 {
    setlocale(0,"Rus");
    int choice;
    printf("Выберите подходящий вариант:\n");
    printf("1 - Перевести из матрицы инцдентности\n");
    printf("2 - Перевести из матрицы смежности\n");
    printf("3 - Перевести из списка смежности\n");
    printf("0 - Закрыть программу\n");
    printf("Ваш выбор: "); scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: MIin(); break;
        case 2: MSin(); break;
        case 3: SSin(); break;
        default: printf("\t Программа закрывается...\n"); break;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
      //определение функций...
void MIin()
{
    int M, N, i, choice;   
    int *A, *B;      
    node **arrayOfList;  
    
    printf("Укажите размеры массива:\n");
    printf("M="); scanf("%d", &M);
    printf("N="); scanf("%d", &N);
    A=(int *)malloc(M*N*sizeof(int));  
    readArray(A, M, N);                     
    printf("-----------------------------------n");
    printf("Ваша матрица инцидентности:\n");
    printArray(A, M, N);   
    printf("----------------------------------\n"); 
    printf("Выберите в какой форме отобразить:\n");
    printf("1 - Перевести в матрицу смежности\n");
    printf("2 - Перевести в список смежности\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
case 1: printf("Перевод в матрицу смежности\n");
    B=(int *)calloc(N*N, sizeof(int));                //выделение памяти для МС
                MI_MS(A, B, M, N);                                //преобразование
    printf("\nПолученная матрица смежности:\n");
    printf("----------------------------------\n");
    printArray(B, N, N);                              //вывод полученной матрицы
    printf("----------------------------------\n");
                free(A);
                free(B);
                break;
        case 2: B=(int *)calloc(N*N, sizeof(int)); //выделение памяти для промежуточной МС
                MI_MS(A, B, M, N);                                //преобразование
                free(A);
    printf("Перевод в список смежности\n");
    arrayOfList=(node **)malloc(N*sizeof(node *));    //выделение памяти для СС
                MS_SS(B, N, arrayOfList);   
    printf("\nПолученный список смежности:\n");
    printf("----------------------------------\n");
                for(i=0; i<N; i++)
                {   
                    printf("%d:", i+1);
                    
printList(*(arrayOfList+i));
                }
    
printf("----------------------------------\n"); 
                free(B); 
                for(i=0; i<N; i++) destroy(*(arrayOfList+i));
                free(arrayOfList);
                break;
        default:printf("\nНеверный выбор...\n"); free(A);
    }
}
void MSin()
{
    int M, N, i, choice; 
    int *A;     
    node **arrayOfList;  

    printf("Укажите кол-во вершин:\n");
    printf("N="); scanf("%d", &N);
    A=(int *)malloc(N*N*sizeof(int));  
    readArray(A, N, N);                     
    printf("----------------------------------\n");
    printf("Матрица смежности:\n");
    printArray(A, N, N);   
    printf("----------------------------------\n");

    printf("Выберите в какой форме отобразить:\n");
    printf("1 - Перевести в список смежности\n");
  printf("2 - Перевести в матрицу инцидентности\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:printf("Перевод в список смежности\n");
    arrayOfList=(node **)malloc(N*sizeof(node *));
                MS_SS(A, N, arrayOfList);   
    printf("\nПолученный список смежности:\n");
    printf("----------------------------------\n");
                for(i=0; i<N; i++)
                {   
                    printf("%d:", i+1);
                    printList(*(arrayOfList+i));
                }
                free(A); 
                for(i=0; i<N; i++) destroy(*(arrayOfList+i));
                free(arrayOfList);
                break;
сase 2:arrayOfList=(node **)malloc(N*sizeof(node *));
                MS_SS(A, N, arrayOfList);   
            M=countInList(arrayOfList, N);
                free(A);
    printf("Перевод в матрицу инцидентности\n");
            A=(int *)calloc(M*N, sizeof(int));
                SS_MI(A, N, arrayOfList);
printf("\nПолученная матрица инцидентности:\n");
printf("----------------------------------------\n");
                printArray(A, M, N);
printf("----------------------------------------\n");
                free(A); 
                for(i=0; i<N; i++) destroy(*(arrayOfList+i));
                free(arrayOfList);
                break;
        default:printf("\nНеверный выбор...\n"); free(A);
    }
}
void SSin()
{
    int M, N, i, choice;   
    int *A, *B;      
    node **arrayOfList;  
    
    printf("\n\t+ Кол-во вершин в графе: "); scanf("%d", &N);
    arrayOfList=(node **)malloc(N*sizeof(node *));                        // выделение памяти под СС
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        printf("Вершина #%d\n", i+1);
        *(arrayOfList+i)=readList();
    }
    printf("----------------------------------\n");
    printf("Список смежности:\n");
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {   
        printf("%d:", i+1);
        printList(*(arrayOfList+i));
    }
    printf("----------------------------------\n"); 
    M=countInList(arrayOfList, N);
    printf("Выберите в какой форме отобразить:\n");
printf("1 - Перевод в матрицу инцидентности\n");
    printf("2 - Перевод в матрицу смежности\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
case 1:printf("Перевод в матрицу инцидентности\n");
        A=(int *)calloc(M*N, sizeof(int));
                SS_MI(A, N, arrayOfList);
    printf("\nПолученная матрица инцидентности:");
printf("\n--------------------------------------\n");
                printArray(A, M, N);
printf("----------------------------------------\n");
                free(A); 
                for(i=0; i<N; i++) destroy(*(arrayOfList+i));
                free(arrayOfList);
                break;
case 2: A=(int *)calloc(M*N, sizeof(int));
                SS_MI(A, N, arrayOfList);
                for(i=0; i<N; i++) destroy(*(arrayOfList+i));
                free(arrayOfList);
            B=(int *)calloc(N*N, sizeof(int));
        printf("Перевод в матрицу смежности\n");
                MI_MS(A, B, M, N);
    printf("\nПолученная матрица смежности:");
printf("\n--------------------------------------\n");
                printArray(B, N, N);
printf("----------------------------------------\n");
                free(A);
                free(B);                    
                break;
        default:printf("\nНеверный выбор\n"); 
                for(i=0; i<N; i++) destroy(*(arrayOfList+i));
                free(arrayOfList);
    }
}

void readArray(int *A, int M, int N)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
       for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
            printf("A[%d][%d]=", i+1, j+1); 
            scanf("%d",(A+i*N+j));
        }
}

node *readList()
{
    int i=0, semn;
    int sizeOfNode=sizeof(node);
    node *A=NULL, *R1, *R2;
    printf("%d :  ", ++i);  scanf("%d",&semn);
    if(semn)
    {
        R1=(node *)malloc(sizeOfNode);
        R1->value=semn; R1->next=NULL;
        A=R1;
        printf("%d :  ", ++i);  scanf("%d",&semn);
    }
    while(semn)
    {
        R2=(node *)malloc(sizeOfNode);
        R2->value=semn; R2->next=NULL;
        R1->next=R2;    R1=R2;
    printf("%d :  ", ++i); scanf("%d",&semn);      
    }
    printf("\n");
    return A;
}


void printArray(int *A, int M, int N)
{
   int i, j;
   for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    {   
   for(j=0; j<N; j++) printf("%3d", *(A+i*N+j));
       printf("\n");
    }
}
void printList(node *R)
{
    int i=0, semn;
    int sizeOfNode=sizeof(node);
    while(R)
    {
        printf("%2d", R->value);
        R=R->next;     
    }
    printf("%2d\n", 0);
}
void MI_MS(int *A, int *B, int M, int N)
{
    int i, j, a, b;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            if(*(A+i*N+j)==2) a=b=j;
            else
            {
                if(*(A+i*N+j)==-1) a=j; 
                if(*(A+i*N+j)==1) b=j; 
            }
        *(B+a*N+b)=1;
    }   
}


void MS_SS(int *A, int N, node **arrayOfList)
{   
    int i, j, k;
    int sizeOfNode=sizeof(node);
    node *R1, *R2;
    
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)   //найти  первую 1 в строке
    {       
        j=0; k=0;
        while(!k&&(j<N)) 
        { 
            if(*(A+i*N+j)) k=j+1;
            j++;
        }
        //k=0 - нет в строке 1 иначе k - номер //первой 1 в строке (отсчёт с 1)
        if(k)
        {
            R1=(node *)malloc(sizeOfNode);
            R1->value=k; R1->next=NULL;
            *(arrayOfList+i)=R1;
            //продолжаем исследовать строку
            while(j<N)
            { 
                if(*(A+i*N+j))
                {
            R2=(node *)malloc(sizeOfNode);
            R2->value=j+1; R2->next=NULL;
                    R1->next=R2;  R1=R2; 
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
        else *(arrayOfList+i)=NULL;
    }
}
void SS_MI(int *A, int N, node **arrayOfList)
{
    int i, j, k=0;
    node *R;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        R=*(arrayOfList+i);
        while(R)
        {
            if((R->value)-1 == i) *(A+k*N+i)=2;
            else
            {
                *(A+k*N+i)=-1;
                *(A+k*N+(R->value)-1)=1;
            }
            R=R->next;
            k++;
        }
    }
}

int countInList(node **arrayOfList, int N)
{
    int i, k=0;
    node *R;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        R=*(arrayOfList+i);
        while(R)
        {
            R=R->next;
            k++;
        }
    }
    return k;
}

void destroy(node *R)
{
   node *TMP;
   while(R)
    {
        TMP=R; 
        R=R->next;
        free(TMP);
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLUvH.jpg
```

Comment: А ошибку привести не хотите?.. И, кстати, если вы пишете в `case` русскую эс, то учтите, что компилятор не сканирует изображение, а читает код...

Comment: Добавил ссылку на скриншот ошибки в вопрос, спасибо, совсем забыл про это)

Comment: @EverSo чтобы вопрос был полезен другим людям, и чтобы не загружать участников необходимостью кликать по ссылкам, текст ошибки следует приводить *прямо в вопросе в виде текста*

Comment: А я вам ответил еще до того... Рекомендую вопрос удалить - слишком уж причина проблемы, гм... несерьезная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в слове `case` буквы `с` и `a` русские.